# Creating an input for each value in an array of strings with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have an a array of strings in my model, I would like to create a text input for each one and bind them to the array, using Twitter Bootstrap typeahead with them. Here is what I have tried:

```
<div class="control-group inline" ng-repeat="offer in userinfoadd.offers">
    <label class="control-label" for="offer">Offer </label>
    <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" bs-typeahead="typeahead" value="{{offer}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my controller:

```
  $scope.userinfoadd = {
     offers: ['one','two','three','four','five']
  };

  //get the typeahead
  $http.get('data/activities.json').success(function(data) { //TODO: Stub, replace for an API call!
    $scope.typeahead = data;
  });
```

Now the inputs render but they don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: By "don't work" you mean typeahead doesn't work?

Comment: typeahead works, but when I change the value it doesn't update the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the model to the input like follows, then it should work:

```
<input type="text" bs-typeahead="typeahead" ng-model="userinfoadd.offers[$index]" />
```

See a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/flek/hwpuT/

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an elegant idea cause Angular re-renders your list once you chance an entry of the array which blurs your input every time you chance 1 character.

Comment: I cannot find another way to do it, not elegant but works at least. Thanks!